# SignalR supplying authorization token

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I'm struggling to decide how best to add authentication and authorisation to my SignalR service.

At the moment it is hosted in Owin alongside a WebApi2 web service. I use OAuth2 bearer tokens to authenticate with those, and it works perfectly. However, I wonder if they're suitable for SignalR?

My client is JavaScript based, and SignalR uses WebSockets if available. This means I can't use the Authorization header. I figured out that I can supply the token using the qs property before I connect. But of course an OAuth2 access token will expire (and relatively shortly in my implementation). I assume that updating the qs property won't make a difference once connected (particularly with web sockets).

I suppose my question is what is the best way to supply a security token, ticket, or any kind of authorization information to SignalR? Preferably a way that can be consistent on both my WebApi and SignalR, but I am looking to know how I *should* be doing it.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at signalR tutorial on security ? at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization

Comment: I have looked through it, but it seems to be more focused on how SignalR mitigates against attacks. I'm looking for information on how I *should* be submitting security information to SignalR in a sensible and compatible way. i.e. show I be using cookies? Does it make sense to use access tokens?

Comment: (continued) From what I can tell, if I use 'qs' to specify an access token on connection, then even after the access token has expired, the connection will remain alive and still know the user. This isn't necessary a problem for me, but should this be the case? At what point do I need to update the qs to provide a new access token (on Reconnect?).

Comment: Hi. Yes, I used the query string approach. You need to modify your SignalR service to look for it there. I had also had to automatically detect the expiration of tokens and update the qs property in case SignalR needed to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

It's been sometime now - but we used to look for the auth cookie in the signalR request to ensure that only a signed in user can subscribe to signalr notifications.

It didn't handle the case where the token expired - since the cookie was checked only on connect. This wasn't a problem for us.